# Unable to Open any notebooks from the cloud

Tags: wolfram-cloud

So anytime I try to open a .nb file that has been saved to the Wolfram Cloud (which is all of my projects), I get the prompt "Why the beep?" containing the message :"https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/kclark85/[project name].nb" could not be found. It is doing this for all of my cloud saved files, even though it is showing me logged in. It just recently started doing this a couple of days ago, and as far as I know I have not downloaded any software or messed with any files that would conflict with cloud storage.

As a test, I created a new .nb file and saved it to the cloud, and now I cannot open that file either.

Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: Is your file actually named `[project name].nb`? That's a weird name for a file. Maybe it's not handling the brackets well? I don't even know if `[` and `]` are  supported in URLs

Comment: no that's not the actual name. It was meant to represent the fact that none of my (previously availabe) cloud files can be opened anymore